# How can I calculate the sum of "letter numbers" in a string?

Tags: php, counter

Is there any built-in PHP function through which I can count the sum of indexes of letters of the alphabet found in a string?

```
<?php
$a = "testword";
echo "Count of Characters is: " . strlen($a); 
?>
```

Now I want to get a cumulative "total" of this word.

e.g.

- `A` is the first letter of the alphabet so it maps to `1`
- `B` is the second letter of the alphabet so it maps to `2`
- `C` is the third letter of the alphabet so it maps to `3`
- `D` is the fourth letter of the alphabet so it maps to `4`

So the word ABCD gives 1+2+3+4=10

Similarly I need a function for "testword" or any word.

Comment: Please explain a bit better what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Im curious why you need this?

Comment: number of alphabets *facepalm*

Comment: no i didn't read.. this a place to share knowledge... u r not a king who is ruling here.. people like you stop others to help.. i'm a newbie in PHP so trying to understand the things and u gave more than 5 demotivating comments. shame on u

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
function WordSum($word)
{
    $cnt = 0;
    $word = strtoupper(trim($word));
    $len = strlen($word);

    for($i = 0; $i < $len; $i++)
    {
        $cnt += ord($word[$i]) - 64; 
    }

    return $cnt;
}

var_dump(WordSum("testword"));
```

Comment: $c is an individual character in the string

Comment: @craig: as you are deducting 64 (i.e ascii of `A`)..you have to convert string in uppercase first.

Comment: hmm ok, but thats why I use strtoupper in the calculation, but I could have uppercased it before hand

Comment: @SimranAshwinArora: Read the documentation for `foreach`.

Comment: it is giving this error Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in

Comment: @SimranAshwinArora, modified to a function, strtoupper outside of loop, and foreach -> for. Should work now?

Comment: @SimranAshwinArora, then I dont understand your problem. What is the expected output? WordSum("abcd") == 10 ;)

Answer (score 0):

Just to show a totally different method, for the sheer pleasure of demonstrating some of PHP's array functions:

```
$data = "testword";

$testResult = array_values(array_merge(array_fill_keys(range('A','Z'),
                                                       0
                                                      ),
                                       array_count_values(str_split(strtoupper($data)
                                                                   )
                                                         )
                                      )
                          );
$wordCount = 0;
foreach($testResult as $letterValue => $letterCount) {
    $wordCount += ++$letterValue * $letterCount;
}

var_dump($wordCount);
```

Answer (score -3):

```
$a = "test";
$b = "word";
echo (strlen($a) + strlen($b));
```

Comment: Your updated answer makes a lot more sense. This is what I understood from it. Apologies